# C# incompatibility in two T types in generic method which return T type

Tags: c#, generics, generic-method

I am trying to return max value of a T[] array by using following method. I don't understand why compiler complains here `T max = _genericList[0];` that throws error `cannot implicitly convert ...\GenericList(9) to ...\GenericList(123)`.

Why these two are different? I want to use the T[] of some GenericList class inctance to interpolate through it and find the maximum/minimum. How is that possible?

```
internal class GenericList<T>
{
    private T[] _genericList;
    private int _count;
    private int _listInnitialLength;

public GenericList(int listLength)
    {
        _genericList = new T[listLength];
        _count = 0;
        _listInnitialLength = listLength;
    }

    public T Max<T>() where T : IComparable
    {
        T max = _genericList[0];
        foreach (T item in _genericList)
        {
                if (Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(item, max) > 0)
                {
                    max = item;
                }
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `T` in method `Max<T>` is not the one defined in your class `GenericList<T>`, even they have a same name. I think you should move the constraint to the class and make `Max` method non-generic.

```
internal class GenericList<T> where T : IComparable
{
    //....
    public T Max()
    {
        //....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much I was not aware that you can`t make a generic method in a generic class using the same type, which is logically corect. It was all my fault.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

```
public T Max<T>() where T : IComparable
```

You just overrided T defined in class declaration. Should be:

```
internal class GenericList<T>  where T : IComparable
{
    private T[] _genericList;
    private int _count;
    private int _listInnitialLength;

    public GenericList(int listLength)
    {
        _genericList = new T[listLength];
        _count = 0;
        _listInnitialLength = listLength;
    }

    public T Max()
    {
        T max = _genericList[0];
        foreach (T item in _genericList)
        {
            if (Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(item, max) > 0)
            {
                max = item;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers will fix your problem, but why use `Comparer<T>.Default` when T already implements [IComparable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey2t2ys5(v=vs.110).aspx)?

```
if (item.CompareTo(max) > 0)
{
    max = item;
}
```